# How to add constant to enum?

Tags: java, enums

I have a enum with some links. In those links is the same version number (`1.1.1`), for now as a String, which I would like to replace with constant. How to do this?
I could edit link while returning it (replace some string with my constant), but it does not seems like clean solution. Thank you for any help!

```
package test.intro;

import test.version;

public enum LinkType
{
  LINK1("test/1.1.1/doc/test1.pdf"),
  LINK2("test/1.1.1/doc/test2.pdf"),
  LINK3("test/1.1.1/doc/test3.pdf");
  
  public final String href;
  //my constant I want to use:
  private final String versionName = version.getVersionName();

  private LinkType(String href)
  {
    this.href = href;
  }

  public String getHref()
  {
    return href;
  }

}
```

Comment: why? if it has the same value for all enums, why have it in there

Comment: @Stultuske hi, because in `test.version` I can update version one day and I do not want update all links in enum manually.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
package test.intro;

import test.version;

public enum LinkType {

  LINK1("test/%s/doc/test1.pdf"),
  LINK2("test/%s/doc/test2.pdf"),
  LINK3("test/%s/doc/test3.pdf");

  public final String hrefTemplate;

  private LinkType(String hrefTemplate) {
    this.hrefTemplate = hrefTemplate;
  }

  public String getHrefTemplate() {
      return this.hrefTemplate;
  }

  public String getHref() {
    return String.format(this.hrefTemplate, version.getVersionName());
    // or return this.hrefTemplate.formatted(version.getVersionName()); if you have Java >= 13

  }

}
```

Comment: or using the constant as requested in question :  `this.hrefTemplate.formatted(versionName);`; or even in the constructor: `this.href = hrefTemplate.formatted(versionName);`

Comment: @user16320675 yes :) depending on what you want and what that `getVersionName()` method really does. But you are absolutely right!

Answer (score 1):

I guess `version.getVersionName()` is a static method?

Then you could just write `LINK1("test/" + version.getVersionName() + "/doc/test1.pdf")` etc.

Comment: Thanks @user3768649, but maybe would be better to call `version.getVersionName()` only once and create some constant?

Comment: if there's an expensive call behind ``version.getVersionName()`` I believe the ``version`` class should handle saving it as a constant. Your enum should not need to concern itself with that. If there's no expensive call behind ``version.getVersionName()``, there's no need for a constant.

Answer (score 0):

I put my enum into new class and created an attribute. Because my enum is called only in one method, it was easy to change. The solution from @David Mališ might be cleaner.

```
package test.intro;

import test.version;

public class TestLinks {
  private final static String versionName = version.getVersionName();

  public enum LinkType {
    LINK1("test/"+versionName+"/doc/test1.pdf"),
      
    //another code
  }
}
```